# How to start app module in multi-module application unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, android-testing

I'm trying to run UI test that when click on the button should open another activity but that activity in another module and I'm open it using intent-filter action, the module which I want to run UI test on it is not know anything about the other module so when espresso clicks on the button `ActivityNotFoundException` will be thrown, but it will not happen if I run the project without unit test it's will work because app module implements both modules.

My Gradle project structure for the app module:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":login")
    implementation project(":main")
}
```

Login module

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':core')
}
```

Main module

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':core')
}
```

Both main and login doesn't know anything about each other, and when I start the main activity from login activity I start it by intent action:

```kotlin
startActivity(Intent("com.example.Main"))
```

This is the manifest file for main module

```xml
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">

    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="com.example.Main" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Because the app module implements both modules it will run without issues, but when starting the UI test it will crash with `ActivityNotFoundException` because the app module will not start if I run the test from the submodule.

I have tried to add the main module to login module

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':core')
    implementation project(':main')
}
```

But if I have in main module button that opens `LoginActivity` and in the login module I have another button to open `MainActivity` I can't do something like this

**Main:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':core')
    implementation project(':login')
}
```

**Login:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':core')
    implementation project(':main')
}
```

it's will be cyclic dependency

Comment: Try using `testImplementation project("...")` to add dependencies for test.